# Python Selenium - clicking on the account confirmation link in the email

Tags: python, selenium, email-confirmation

I want to write a test in selenium python. This is what i would like to acheive.

Steps:

1. Create an account on XYZ
2. then, go to gmail or outlook
3. Go to inbox mail
4. find confirmation email
5. click on the confirmation email
6. Logout

I would like to know if it is a good idea to login to gmail or outlook and click on each elements using browser. Is there any python library that i can use to achieve this without using a browser?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like `urllib` or `requests` can does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the easiest way of getting the confirmation mail is using the module `poplib`. Just receive the mails and look for the URL with a regular expression. The open is with `urllib`.

Example from the docs:

```
import poplib

M = poplib.POP3("pop.gmail.com")
M.user("user")
M.pass_("pass")
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print j
```